# Unable to install MetaTrader5

Tags: python, pip, metatrader5

I could not install MetaTrader5 by:

pip install MetaTrader5

I got the following error:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MetaTrader5 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for MetaTrader5

Knowing that I am on MAC laptop and I have Python 3.7.6

Thanks in advance to provide me the solution

Comment: Alright, what do/don't you understand from that error message?

Comment: You can use it via this package: https://pypi.org/project/mt5linux/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`MetaTrader5` [provides](https://pypi.org/project/MetaTrader5/5.0.31/#files) a lot of binary wheels but only for w32 and w64. No Linux, no MacOS and no source code. It seems the software is Windows-only.

Their site [recommends](https://www.mql5.com/en/articles/619) to use one of the w32/w64 emulators on MacOS.

Comment: Their site also talks about running terminal under Wine - unfortunately MetaTrader5 Python Package will not work under Linux...

Comment: @AndyThompson The same as for MacOS — use an emulator. Wine, VirtualBox, qemu, Docker…

Comment: The pythom package from metatrader will not import in wine hence my original comment

Comment: It's working just fine in Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: @JanibSoomro Not Ubuntu — it's Wine emulator which I [mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61143812/unable-to-install-metatrader5/61144210#comment120757883_61144210).

Comment: Yes, I meant Wine in Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 2):

Folks at MQT5 haven't compiled any version for Linux so far and the only method available is to Installed Python3.x for Windows inside Wine64 and then continue further pip installation accordingly.

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 and successfully installed MetaTrader5, here are the steps.

- sudo apt update -y
- sudo apt upgrade -y
- sudo apt install wine64
- cd ~/Desktop
- wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.0/python-3.8.0-amd64.exe --no-check-certificate
- wget https://download.mql5.com/cdn/web/metaquotes.software.corp/mt5/mt5setup.exe  --no-check-certificate
- wine64 uninstaller -> select install and then select mt5setup.exe
- wine64 cmd
- cd /folder_where_python3.8_setup.exe
- python-3.8.0-amd64.exe
- c:
- cd windows
- copy py.exe python.exe
- python -m pip install pip --upgrade
- exit
- wine64 cmd
- pip3 --version
- pip3 install jupyter
- pip3 install MetaTrader5
- jupyter notebook

This seems to work, I can access MetaTrader5 repository however jupyter crashes when any ipynb file is loaded. Haven't found any solution for this problem but if you save everything in a .py file and execute it normally, it works fine.

Comment: I can confirm this works as of 2023. Please note that you must use python >= 3.8, up to python 3.10 (as of 2023, jan) since the MT5 pip package only supports those versions currently. Otherwise you will get the error "No matching distribution found for MetaTrader5"

Answer (score 0):

only python 3.8.* working or install with pip packge MetaTrader5